# Sending an Email Using win32com with a Buffer as Attachments

Tags: python, win32com, stringio

I'm trying to write a script that will be deployed as a lambda, and supposed to send an automatic emails with some dfs as attachments. Our company using outlook, so I'm using win32com.Client.
For some reason, I can't using StringIo as a buffer here. Is any one can help me?

This is the code I tried:

```
def emailing_alerts(df):
    ol = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
    olmailitem = 0x0
    newmail = ol.CreateItem(olmailitem)
    newmail.Subject = 'Testing Mail - Deployment Alerts'
    newmail.To = 'example@company.com'
    newmail.Body = f"Hi all, \n" \
               f"This is a test email to see whether my pipeline-alerts works."
    csv_buffer = StringIO()
    df.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False)
    newmail.Attachments.Add(Source=csv_buffer.getvalue())
    newmail.Send()
    print(f"The mail was send successfully")
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add It looks like Outlook expects to find a file on a file-system (as a string parameter), not a buffer of data. Without stating the obvious, is it possible to write the DataFrame to a temp directory, and attach that file?

Comment: I want to deploy it as an aws lambda so I don't know whether is that possible